# Google Tag Manager purpose on iOS

Tags: ios, google-tag-manager

Can somebody please explain me what is the purpose of using Google Tag Manager (GTM) on an iOS app?
Currently I am working on an app which part of the legacy configuration resides on GTM but I cannot find any purpose of this.

I've read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/) but I find it very confusing.

It mentions to add `GoogleTagManager` pod, add the json corresponding to your container and "preview" it with a Custom URL Schema.

The things that I dont understand are:

1. Why adding `GoogleTagManager` pod if you are not using it in your app, there is no import or anything like that
2. Why download the container (json file) and add it into your project. Based on the documentation, it doesnt mention anything about linking this json file with your actual xcode project.
3. How by using a custom URL Schema will test your container? On the documentation doesnt mention anything about handling this custom URL schema.

So based on the documentation I dont find any purpose of using GTM at all. The thing that for me makes sense is when login an event using Google Analytics, by calling `Analytics.logEvent...`, but this is Google Analytics, not GTM.

I will appreciate if someone can provide some information about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager is used, when you want to change some custom event data on the build which is already live(on App store) and you don't want to resubmit the new build just for the event. For more details you can refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/).

Comment: thanks for your response, I understand that part, change some event data without releasing a new build. But why adding a new pod into the project, what is the purpose of downloading a json file? and what about the custom URL schema?? 